# WPF, localisation: reevaluating control values

Tags: wpf, localization, properties, markup-extensions

I'm doing a small research on localisation methods in WPF. I heard about the idea with markup extension:

`<Label Content="{local:Translate {-- label ID here --}}" />`

I like this solution very much: it's extremely easy to implement and seems to be nicely flexible. I've got one concern, however. Let's suppose, that user changes the locale in the runtime. How to ensure, that localized properties will be reevaluated to match new language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to call [DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.invalidateproperty.aspx). Keep in mind that if you were binding to an object implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` they would reevaluate by way of the underlying data changing.

`DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty` can be called on a given `DependencyProperty` such as `Label.Content`.

```
Label label = new Label();
label.InvalidateProperty(ContentProperty);
```

This would have to be done for the varying properties that need re-evaluation. There is an in depth [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx) around localization within WPF for varying alternatives as well that should be investigated.

Comment: Can you please tell me a little bit more about it? Shall I call this method on every control I localize?

Comment: Thank you. I've managed to write small proof-of-concept application with the binding (the markup extension will generate one eventually). However, I cannot make WPF reevaluate the Content property of button. The XAML is here [link](http://pastebin.com/MuSEMR95) and C# source here [link](http://pastebin.com/8m0nPgkJ). Can you please tell me, what have I done wrong?

Comment: @Sppok Not working here either; opened a question around the behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926748/dependencyobject-invalidateproperty-not-working