# DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty not working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.invalidateproperty.aspx) via MSDN...

> You can also use InvalidateProperty to
>   force re-evaluation of a binding
>   against a data source that is not able
>   to implement the recommended
>   INotifyPropertyChanged notification
>   mechanism...

...the code below should work, yet it doesn't.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private Payload _payload = new Payload();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = _payload;
    }

    private void Invalidate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _payload.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)).ToLongTimeString();

        Button b = sender as Button;
        b.InvalidateProperty(Button.ContentProperty);
    }
}

public class Payload
{
    private String _payload = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    public String Timestamp 
    {
        get
        {
            return _payload;
        }
        set
        {
            _payload = value;
        }
   }
}

<Grid>
    <Button Click="Invalidate"
            Width="100" 
            Height="50" 
            Content="{Binding Path=Timestamp}"/>
</Grid>
```

Any idea what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you mentioned, it ought to work but doesn't.  But there is a simple workaround:

```
// Doesn't work:
//b.InvalidateProperty(Button.ContentProperty);

// Works:
BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(b, Button.ContentProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

I debugged into the reference source and all `InvalidateProperty` does in your situation is cause a cached value to be re-read from the `BindingExpression` into the `Button` `Content` property.  Offhand, I don't know when this would even be necessary but it's not useful to get the `BindingExpression` to re-read the raw property.

Since the workaround is convenient and general, the only further effort warranted is filing a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: @Rick Is the value being re-read or re-evaluated? If it is being re-evaluated via the property which is bound the new value should propagate. If the it is simply being re-read then it sounds like it is still using a cached value?

Comment: @Aaron, these words are ambiguous: "re-read" and "re-evaluate".  For example, during the execution of the `InvalidateProperty`, the  statement `expr.Evaluate()` runs.  That sure sounds like "re-evaluate" but in fact it just "re-reads" the cached value.  So it's not black and white.  There are a dozens of edge cases that InvalidateProperty handles.  Is this the first time?.  Are we setting the value?  Is this part of an animation?  Is there a parent binding expression?  And none of them seem to be related to whether the source implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @Aaron: Ran out of room...  Since a binding expression supports caching, and evaluation can return the cached value, the word we're looking for is "update" as in `UpdateTarget`.  Our wish when we invalidate the property is for its binding expression to update its target.  That is, for it to update the target **from the source**.  Since this is what we want, and since we can do it directly ourselves, the clearest and most reliable approach is to do just that instead.

Comment: @Rick This is not a real problem per se; just something I stumbled upon so finding a solution is not necessarily the end goal. Wanting to understand the fundamental reason for it not working as theorized based on the documentation.  Any info into what causes that cached value to expire? That may be the missing link. Since the expression can store a cached value something needs to expire that value. Thanks again for work on this...

Comment: @Aaron: I'm curious too.  There are tens of thousands of lines of code involved so I can't say I really grok the code, just the path I debugged.  But empirically we can say that the cache is refreshed when 1) `PropertyChanged` fires (if any), 2) the binding expression changes, or 3) `UpdateTarget` is called.  It's called a cache in the code but a better name would be a snapshot.

Comment: @Rick Fair enough...thanks for the all the input. May file a bug and if so I will update the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I have an idea.

The reason why your code doesn't work is that button asks for new value, but Binding object holds the old one as it hasn't got PropertyChanged notification. The changes chain in standart scenario looks like:

> Payload.Timestamp -> Binding object -> Button.ContentProperty

In your scenario, when you call `InvalidateProperty` chain is:

> Binding object -> Button.ContentProperty

So, you should notify binding object that its source has been changed with next code:

```
    private void Invalidate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _payload.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)).ToLongTimeString();

        Button b = sender as Button;
        BindingExpression be = b.GetBindingExpression(Button.ContentProperty);
        be.UpdateTarget();
    }
```

As you can see, I even shouldn't call `InvalidateProperty`, because the Binding mechanizm due to changed underlying source will automatically force Button to refresh content.

Comment: This is forcing the change to occur from the source to the target by completely by-passing InvalidateProperty. Based on the MSDN documentation the InvalidateProperty should force a re-evaluation against the source which does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged; updating the target is explicit and another way to achieve the same result but I am curious why InvalidateProperty is not behaving as expected

Answer (score 1):

we never got it working either, here's the function which does the trick:

```
private void InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty property,
    FrameworkElement container)
{
    container.SetBinding(property, 
        container.GetBindingExpression(property).ParentBinding);
}
```

And here's how we call it:

```
private void Invalidate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _payload.Timestamp = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)).ToLongTimeString();

    Button b = sender as Button;

    //b.InvalidateProperty(Button.ContentProperty);
    this.InvalidateProperty(Button.ContentProperty, b);
}
```

I also had to set DataContext to _payload.

Comment: Perhaps we could make it a bit sweater by using an extension method.

Comment: Thanks for the information; I am curious as to why it is not working. Are we fundamentally using it wrong? Is it perhaps a bug within the framework?