# Why is my dependency property binding not updating?

Tags: wpf

I have tried to create a MultiConverter that compares a CurrentUser's permission level to a subset of permissions from an enum, in order to toggle visibility of certain buttons.  My converter is called at startup when the UserControl is created, but if I modify the CurrentUser's level after that, the converter is not called again.

The basic structure is:

KioskController owns UserInfo owns CurrentUser owns Level.  I am binding to, and updating, CurrentUser.Level.  Important snippets follow:

```
<Image x:Name="Redeem" Height="114" Width="178" Source="Graphics\MAINMENU_Redeem.png" Margin="128,260,718,394">
        <Image.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource theIntPermissionToVisibilityConverter}">
                <Binding Path="_UserInfo.CurrentUser.Level"/>
                <Binding Source="{x:Static local:UserInfo+UserLevel.Cashier}"/>
                <Binding Source="{x:Static local:UserInfo+UserLevel.Manager}"/>
                <Binding Source="{x:Static local:UserInfo+UserLevel.Tech}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Image.Visibility>
    </Image>
```

The KioskController:

```
public  sealed class KC : DependencyObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Singleton interface to the Kiosk Controller
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        #region _UserInfoDependencyProperty
        public UserInfo _UserInfo
        {
            get { return (UserInfo)this.GetValue(_UserInfoProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(_UserInfoProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty _UserInfoProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                            "_UserInfo", typeof(UserInfo), typeof(KC), new PropertyMetadata(null));


        #endregion
```

The UserInfo class:

```
public class UserInfo : DependencyObject
    {
 #region CurrentUserProperty
        public User CurrentUser
        {
            get { return (User)this.GetValue(CurrentUserProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(CurrentUserProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentUserProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                            "CurrentUser", typeof(User), typeof(UserInfo), new PropertyMetadata(null));


        #endregion
```

And finally the user class:

```
  public class User : DependencyObject 
        {
#region UserLevelProperty
            public UserInfo.UserLevel Level
            {
                get { return (UserInfo.UserLevel)this.GetValue(LevelProperty); }
                set { this.SetValue(LevelProperty, value); }
            }
            public static readonly DependencyProperty LevelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                "UserLevel", typeof(UserInfo.UserLevel), typeof(User), new PropertyMetadata(UserInfo.UserLevel.Invalid));


            #endregion
```

I am setting the DataContext of the usercontrol to my KioskController, and that appears to be working.  I've tested a simple string binding in a textblock, and it showed up ok.

Finally, the call that updates CurrentUser, triggers the Setter, but never causes the converter to be called again:

```
CurrentUser.Level = theUser.Level;
```

I have binding errors enabled in the console window, and I don't see any problems in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, changing a DependencyProperty will cause an element bound to it to update, but it will not cause the converter to re-evalute.  This appears to be generally considered as an oversight or bug.  The solution is to force the reevaluation of the converter:

```
 MultiBindingExpression be = BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression(Redeem, Image.VisibilityProperty);
            be.UpdateTarget();
```

or for a single binding converter:

```
BindingExpression be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(Redeem, Image.VisibilityProperty);
            be.UpdateTarget();
```

This is a little unfriendly, however, because your codebehind needs to be aware of the bindings you have in your XAML, and call this operation for each object using the converter in question.  if there is a solution using iNotifyPropertyChanged, I would like to see it.

This link helped solve the problem:  [DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926748/dependencyobject-invalidateproperty-not-working)